# communities redirect to previous page on button click

Tags: customer-community, redirect

I am facing issue with redirect to previous page in community. My current page url is like this

> **`http://communityurl.com/Mysecondpage?id=01p7A123456AmUo`**

i am passing id value from MyFirstPage. I have tried with following javascript code to redirect to previous page. But it is not working , it is loading and staying on same page.

```
**<button class="button1" onclick="redirect();"> Back </button>


 function redirect(){
                var url = window.location.href; 
                var value = url.substr(0,url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                value= value+'MyFirstPage';
                console.log(value);
                window.open(value, '_self');
        }**
```

Please suggest how to redirect to another page , when user clicks on Back button!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Works fine in my test (albeit using a visual force page not in a community). Do you get any errors in the console? Does the URL look correct?

Comment: Eric, It was working fine in vf page preview mode. When i am checking in community it is showing same page.  it is not redirecting to first page   . Any permission need to give in community . Please suggest                       http://communityurl.com/Mysecondpage?id=01p7A123456AmUo

Comment: I have resolved using this code in communities. Thanks for your suggestions and help.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved using this code in communities. Thanks for your suggestions and help.

```
****<button class="button1" onclick="return redirect();"> Back </button>

function redirect(){
                var url = window.location.href; 
                var value = url.substr(0,url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                value= value+'MyFirstPage';
                console.log(value);
                window.open(value, '_self');
               return false;

        }****
```

We have to write return in javascript , so that it will redirect to another page